# C# app corrupts cortana and other windows apps

Tags: windows, windows-10, c#, cortana

I wrote an update for one of my C# apps, basic bug fixing stuff like Empty-Checks for textboxes and UI make up, no new features, same external DLL versions.

While testing it on my VM's I noticed something strange. After using the app for about 2 minutes all desktop icons were missing and the search in the start menu was not working anymore. The only thing it would find were web results. All icons in the taskbar looked like a white sheet of paper.

I checked the event log and found that cortana, SearchUI.exe, HxTsr.exe, OneConnect, OneDrive and many other windows apps and services had thrown exceptions.

Exceptions like:

```
Error loading application settings for package "microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe". Error code: -2147024893
```

```
The repair for operation LocalSettings and package microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe with error -2147009096 returned the error code -2147009279.
```

More error logs:
https://we.tl/t-2uDfMDP4cN

I don't use cortana functions or anything related to those windows features.

I continued testing it on more VM's; different OS's, Win10(32/64bit), Win8.1(32/64bit). Same result every time. After a few minutes the desktop background goes black and all icons disapear.(Its not a problem with the VM's; I created new ones)

It's not a problem with windows update (Checked articles like this one https://windowsreport.com/cortana-windows-10-problems/ performed sfc scans and Powershell repair routines; did not fix the issue) nor with the Visual Studio Setup Project installer(issue persist if I copy the files manualy)

If anyone has an idea how minor code changes can cause such an error please help.

Thanks

Comment: are you sure it's a problem of the update? (have you also tried running the previous version in the same circumstances to confirm it's due to the changes?)

Comment: Yes, I ran the old version on the same VM's with no problem than performed the update(ether through copying the new .exe in the program folder or through running the new setup.msi)